# Unity3d Prime31 iCloud iOS: An app id with identifier xx.xxx.xxx is not available

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, icloud, prime31

I added the Prime31 iCloud iOS plugin to my project running on Unity v5.3.4f1 and built it in release mode, then enabled iCloud with key-value storage only ticked in Xcode. The app id in the developer portal already had iCloud enabled. The development build worked without issues on my test device and synced data nicely. I archived the project and tried to upload it to Apple as an update to my existing app, and this step always failed with the following message:

> failed to locate or generate matching signing assets identifier not
>   available An app id with identifier xx.xxx.xxx is not available

I worked 2 full days trying to resolve this issue and tried every possible solution out there:
- Regenerating provisioning profiles
- Deleting existing provisioning profiles and downloading them again
- Downgrading to Xcode 7.2.1 and then back to 7.3
- Checking all certificates and replacing expired ones
- made sure all the certs, provisioning profiles and app IDs are in sync
- Specifying the provisioning profile and code signing identity instead of leaving them set to auto

None worked, eventually I just deleted all traces of the Prime31 iCloud plugin code and the upload worked without problems. I would really like to add Prime31 iCloud functionality to my app and would appreciate your help.

Comment: just FTR, you asked on Prime31's own forum right???  I'm afraid we have not used their iCloud plugin so I can't help on that one.

Comment: I did and their reply was that this was Apple's problem and not theirs.

Comment: Right. It's tough when P31 is unhelpful like that  :/

Comment: I'm trying hard to hide my true feelings :)

Comment: Are you sure that iCloud service is enabled for your AppID for distribution? (in Apple developer portal)

Comment: Yes and also enabled in build settings capabilities. I mean it works totally find on my device in both debug and release mode, it just fails on upload and sometimes on archive too.

Comment: Well, it was a random idea about what could have been wrong. Looks like I can't help you... :( But I would say that there is a chance that it's not Prime31's fault. Anyway, good look fighting with this thing. May the Force be with you :)